# Process Sentinel-5p HDF5 / NetCDF to TIFF files but overlapping appears clearly between two files

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, hdf5, sentinel-5p

I've used 2 Sentinel-5p scenes in HDF5 / NetCDF to GeoTIFF by GDAL like below:
First, I extract the lat and lon coordinates from the HDF5 file.

```
 gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"S5P_OFFL_L2__AER_AI_20210501T110005_20210501T124135_18388_01_010400_20210503T005051.nc"://PRODUCT/latitude lat.vrt
 gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"S5P_OFFL_L2__AER_AI_20210501T110005_20210501T124135_18388_01_010400_20210503T005051.nc"://PRODUCT/longitude lon.vrt
```

Then, I create the product.vrt like below

```
    <VRTDataset rasterXSize="450" rasterYSize="3735">
  <Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
    <MDI key="LINE_OFFSET">0</MDI>
    <MDI key="LINE_STEP">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</MDI>
    <MDI key="PIXEL_STEP">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="X_DATASET">/home/PROJECTS/Sentinel-5P/test_L2_AER_AI/lon.vrt</MDI>
    <MDI key="Y_BAND">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="Y_DATASET">/home/PROJECTS/Sentinel-5P/test_L2_AER_AI/lat.vrt</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">9.9692099683869e+36</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">7.78603750784e+35</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">-7.209698677063</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">2.6750402750247e+36</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">HDF5:S5P_OFFL_L2__AER_AI_20210501T110005_20210501T124135_18388_01_010400_20210503T005051.nc://PRODUCT/aerosol_index_340_380</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="450" RasterYSize="3735" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="225" BlockYSize="1868" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="3735" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="3735" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

And finally, I extract the data inside the HDF5 to GeoTIFF in EPSG:4326

```
gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 9.96921e+36f product.vrt aerosol_index_340_380.tiff -tr 0.069 0.069 -tap -of GTiff
```

I did that for two files which are neighbor to extract the wanted sub_dataset to tiff files and then opened them on QGIS. The image looks like below https://i.stack.imgur.com/S73ri.jpg

[image]

I wonder, why there are clear borders (the line in the middle) between the two overlapping files?

** The two extracted tiff files (7 MB) can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lOXyJXhhzmfs5e_WTsKPOj96CHEEIyhP?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you let QGIS to apply an automatic Min/Max stretch for both images instead of "No Enhancemant"?

Comment: @user30184 with "No Enhancement" QGIS shows gray images which I cannot see any pixels which have data. The two tiff files can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lOXyJXhhzmfs5e_WTsKPOj96CHEEIyhP?usp=sharing

Comment: The take the min/max values from one image and apply the same values  to another image.

Comment: Ok, same min/max values for both images does not make the tones to fit. I am clueless.